# RAILS - Using Ransack as a filter. Is there a way for me to add a link to a page that leads to a filtered link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ransack

I have a model for my Contracts and then another model for my Contract Status.

Right now when any contract is marked from active to inactive it creates a new item in my Contract Status page every single time the status changes.

I would like to add a link to the contract page that leads to the Contract Status page with that specific project already filtered.

I have this as my link now and it'll link to localhost:3000/projectstatus?contract_name_eq=Sample+Contract

But it is still displaying all of my contracts

```
<%= link_to 'Contract Status', contract_status_path(contract_name_eq: contract.name), class: 'dropdown-item' %>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: While answering your own questions can be a good way to share your knowledge the answer should never be one that can only be gained with information that only you know. In this case how you're passing the parameters in your controller to Ransack. If thats the case either delete the question or update it to include a full example so that its actually relevant to others.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this:
<%= link_to 'Contract Status', contract_status_path(q: {contract_name_eq: contract.name}), class: 'dropdown-item' %>